# Unable to edit a file in Linux using shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am using redhat Linux.I am writing a script and I want to # a line in a file and add another line below that,please tell me the command to do that.I am trying with sed command but both the things are not happening.

For eg:
In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I want to append `ClientAliveCountMax 3` before `ClientAliveCountMax 0` and `#ClientAliveCountMax 0`.

Comment: Got a code snippet which does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/ClientAliveCountMax 0/ClientAliveCountMax 3 \
 #ClientAliveCountMax 0/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/ClientAliveCountMax 0/ClientAliveCountMax 3\n\#&' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed 's/\(ClientAliveCountMax.*\)/ClientAliveCountMax 3 \
#\1/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Using GNU awk

```
awk '/ClientAliveCountMax/{$0="ClientAliveCountMax 3\n#"$0}1' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```